# Initial Git setup and git add issue

Tags: git, ubuntu, installation

I init Git on Ubuntu in `www/project-name` folder. So there is `.git` folder. Now the files I need to add to the repo located `www` folder. Any attempts to `git add ../../www` and similar didn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Git will only track files *within* the repo. And it won't track directories at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the .git directory needs to be at the top level directory, so you need: project-name/www, with the .git file in the project-name directory.

Comment: I just tried that and it seems to work. Thank you Randy.